# Alertdialog not shown

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-alertdialog

I have an activity with an EditText and (momentary 2 Buttons). When a Button is pressed, the data from EditText is checked for empty or null string. If so an AlertDialog should be shown. This should be repeated until the result from TextEdit is not empty.
This works fine as long as I do not have any further processing in the Activity. If I have I have further insructions the Alertdialog is not shown. Th step by step dubugging shows the apllication goes into the check, creates the Alertdialog but it is not shown, instead the next instruction in the code is performed. So it makes no sense. The Application **must** stop processing at the point where the Alertdialog is shown.
Once a non empty string is received it should be checked against a textfile with various SQL injection strings and raise a Progressdialog showing the progress of the test.If the test is positive it should return to the EditText to allow correction of the data.
So far tho the behaviour is the same for all Buttons. So I believe it would be the the best way to create an own (inner) class for these actions. 
The further actions (not yet implented) should be: One Button will then call another activity asking for manual completion of the data, the others will try to fetch the missing data from various internet resources. and show the results in another activity, allowing selection of the correct data. The complete data will then be sent to a database. (One reason for testing against SQL injection strings)

Here is the code:

```
public class BlahverwaltungDateneingabeActivity extends Activity {

    public String vtitel=null;  //Variable, der der Wert des Texteingabefeldes zugewiesen werden soll
    public String vtitel_1 = null; //Variable für Stringmanipulation
    private EditText input_vtitel; //Texteingabefeld
    public static Boolean inject_2=false;
    final Context context_1=this;
    Toast einToast;

//  private String filename=getString(R.string.Tempfile_fuer_Blahdaten); // Temporäres File für Blahdaten


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blahverwaltung_dateneingabe_1);

        Button manuellButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.manuell_button);
        Button ofdbButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blah_button);


        //OnClicklistener erzeugen

        manuellButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                input_vtitel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Blahtitel); //Texteingabefeld initialisieren
                vtitel = input_vtitel.getText().toString();  //Texteingabe String zuweisen

                if (vtitel.equals(null) || vtitel.equals("")) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb_1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context_1); //Alertdialog wenn Texteingabe leer
                    adb_1.setTitle(R.string.Nullstring); //Alertdialgo Titel setzen
                    adb_1.setMessage(R.string.Nullstring_1); //AlertNachricht setzen
                    adb_1.setCancelable(false); //kann nicht durch Back abgebrochen werden
                    adb_1.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    //OnClickListener erzeugen
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {     //Activity neu starten
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {     //Methode zum Neustart in Abhängigkeit vom SDK wählen
                                recreate();
                            } else {
                                Intent in_1 = getIntent();
                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                in_1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                                finish();

                                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                                startActivity(in_1);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog ad_1 = adb_1.create();     //Alertdialig erzeugen
                    ad_1.show();
                                             //Alertdialog anzeigen
                }
                InjectionDialog id_1= new InjectionDialog(BlahverwaltungDateneingabeActivity.this);
                id_1.execute(vtitel);
                try {
                    inject_2=id_1.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


//                vtitel_1 = vtitel.replace(" ", "+"); //Leerzeichen durch "+" ersetzen
/*
                try {
                    outputstream_1 = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    outputstream_1.write(vtitel.getBytes());
                    outputstream_1.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
*/

            });
        }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.blahverwaltung_dateneingabe, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

If you provide help, please explain as much as possible, I'm a Java/Android newbie and do sometimes not fully understand what I am doing. THe learning books and  internet sources are often not helpfull. I'm able to adopt provided solutions but I also want to understand why it is done that way and what the code is doing.

BTW: As I mentioned above the data may be sent to the interent, so how can make sure no html hacking, cross site scripting java script, php attack code is in the data when it is sent? aRe there also some comon strings I can check the data strings against?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, no one answered my questions so far. So I will try to do it myself. The above code sample I have completely rewritten and did a lot of step by step debugging on it to understand the behaviour of Android program exectuion and variables initialisation and assignment.

I'll now explain what I understood so far. If there are any errors, please correct me.

Here is the new code, still not complete and it still contains some useless "debugging",  sometimes causing endless loops code I added to understand how program exectuion and variables assignment work.

```
public class BlahverwaltungDateneingabeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public String vtitel_1 = null; //Variable für Stringmanipulation
    public static Boolean inject_2=false;
    private Button manuell_Button;
    private Button ofdb_Button;
    Context context_1=BlahverwaltungDateneingabeActivity.this;
    Toast einToast;

//  private String filename=getString(R.string.Tempfile_fuer_Blahdaten); // Temporäres File für Blahdaten


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_blahverwaltung_dateneingabe_1);

        manuell_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.manuell_button);
        manuell_Button.setOnClickListener(this);

        ofdb_Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ofdb_button);
        ofdb_Button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText input_vtitel =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.Blahtitel);

        String vtitel = input_vtitel.getText().toString();

        if (vtitel.length() == 0) {
            new Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.Nullstring)
                    .setMessage(R.string.NullstringText)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .show();
            return;
        } else {
            Builder adb_2 = new Builder(this);
            adb_2.setTitle(R.string.SQLInjectionPruefung)
                 .setCancelable(false)
                 .setIcon(R.drawable.sand_glass_23654_150)
                 .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, null);
            AlertDialog ad_2 = adb_2.create();
            ad_2.show();
            Button okButton = ad_2.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            okButton.setEnabled(false);
            inject_2=InjectionCheck.InjectionCheckResult(context_1, vtitel);
            okButton.setEnabled(true);
            okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v_1) {
                    Toast.makeText(VideoverwaltungDateneingabeActivity.this, "testtest", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            Toast.makeText(this, "testtesttest", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (inject_2) {
                okButton.performClick();
                new Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.SQLInjectionResult)
                        .setMessage(R.string.SQLInjectionResultText)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, null)
                        .show();
                return;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_blahverwaltung_dateneingabe, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

First change, I'm now implementing the OnClicklistener into my Activity.

```
 public class BlahverwaltungDateneingabeActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
```

The advantage: I do not need to create a new instance of OnClickListener for every Button.

second change, I have an button independent OnClick method.
The advantage: All code stuff that is identical for all Activity buttnos I can put here. It does not matter which button is clicked the code in this method is executed for **all** Activity buttons.

Later I will only have to check which button was clicked like if (v == manuell_Button)... and can put the button specific code there. (I hope this will work)

Ok, now lets assume you have nothing entered in the EditText field and click a button. What will happen now?

the program exectutes

```
String vtitel = input_vtitel.getText().toString();
```

which will result in an "" empty string.

Next it will go into

```
if (vtitel.length() == 0)
```

and because we have an empty string with length = 0 execute the instructions there.

```
new Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.Nullstring)
        .setMessage(R.string.NullstringText)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setNeutralButton(R.string.ok, null)
        .show();
return;
```

This code seems to be executed en block. Although I set a breakpoint on the return instruction it never stopped there.
It does not show the AlerDialog yet, instead it jumps to the end of the OnClick method. Then it invokes view.java, without showing the dialog, then handler.java - still not showing the dialog and finally looper.java and here the dialog is displayed.
Because I haven't implemented an OnClicklstener for the dialog button clicking the button will dismiss the dialog without further action and return to the Activity.

Now lets assume you entered something into the TextEdit field.
Then the program will go into the "else" tree of the "if (vtitel.length() == 0)" instruction. It will execute **all** appropiate steps from the tree without showing an Alertdialog then perform any appropiate actions from the remaining code in the Activity and then again invoke view.java, handler.java and looper.java before showing the dialog.

This makes it nearly impossible to create behaviour like this:

1. raise an dialog
2. stop program execution and wait for user action
3. perform further code depending on the user response

In my code the user input is checked against a file with injection strings. My original intention was and is to display a dialog while the check is performed then automatically dismiss the dialog and continue with the program depending on the result of the check. 
My file is small and does not cause much delay so I tried with adding a Thread.sleep() instruction or putting the check in a for loop and let it run 100 times. It does not matter the result is the same the instruction is performed **before** showing the AlertDialog. So in this case an AlertDialog is useless.
Another possibility would have been a ProgressDialog but here I have similiar problems. The ProgressDialog runs independent from the Activity, means while the Progressdialog is runnung the Activity performs further actions. But the Activity needs the results from the Progressdialog. The second problem, there is no easy way to pass the results of the Progressdialog back to the Activity.The ProgressDialog.get() method works but also prevents the ProgressDialog from showing.The OnPostExecute method is also not usable, It seems it is not designed to pass any results back to the Activity although it is performed in the Activity thread. Here I'm stuck at the moment. It looks there is no easy way to achieve the behaviour I want and I have to find ways to deal with the behaviour of Android programs without losing to much of the functionality I want.